# Can't login to iMac even with correct password first time, works with the same password after another user logs in and logs out

Tags: macos, password, login

I use an iMac (late 2013, with Sierra v10.12.6) where 3 user accounts are setup. Every time I login after restart, I am not able to login with my account (say, user1) even with the correct password, the password box just shakes indicating wrong password.

Then, user2 is able to login into his account with his own password. After that, he logs out and I try logging in as user1 with the same password used as before, it lets me in.

This happens every time, so I have to ask user2 to login first, logout and then, I try logging in. I have tried resetting my password few times, but the same scenario happens after every restart.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and can advise any options here ? I do not want to delete any of these accounts and create afresh.

Comment: Did you use FileVault to encrypt the iMac's disk?

Comment: Could you test all the characters of user1 password in the name window to check if you aren't in the wrong keyboard mode?

Comment: Yes, FileVault is enabled, so Automatic Login as well as the option to type both user name and password is disabled. After restart, I just see icons for the 3 user accounts present and I can type only the password. I don't get to type the password in the username field to check the keyboard mode.

Comment: Could you add the Filevault info. in your OQ? (I could do it for you.) Could you check if user1 is in the allowed users to open the FileVault disk?

Answer (score 1):

The comment from daniel Azuelos provided the solution for me. I had to remove and re-add my own user to the Filevault (since I was added already apparently):

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user myuser
sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd myuser
```